Is there any way to use a stream cipher algorithm(ChaCha20, RC4...) to encrypt a video while still be able to play and stream the encrypted video?
I'm having a project that requires using a stream cipher (ChaCha20 for example) to encrypt a video  and i want to transfer the encrypted video using ffmpeg so that the receiver can decrypt and watch it, but i realized that when the encryption process finished, the file was no longer maintain it's playability so ffmpeg can't do anything with it
This is the python code that i've used before:
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import os

def encrypt_video(input_file, output_file, key, nonce):
    algorithm = algorithms.ChaCha20(key, nonce)
    cipher = Cipher(algorithm, mode=None, backend=default_backend())
    encryptor = cipher.encryptor()

    with open(input_file, 'rb') as f_in, open(output_file, 'wb') as f_out:
        while chunk := f_in.read():  
            encrypted_chunk = encryptor.update(chunk)
            f_out.write(encrypted_chunk)
        f_out.write(encryptor.finalize())

def decrypt_video(input_file, output_file, key, nonce):
    algorithm = algorithms.ChaCha20(key, nonce)
    cipher = Cipher(algorithm, mode=None, backend=default_backend())
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()

    with open(input_file, 'rb') as f_in, open(output_file, 'wb') as f_out:
        while chunk := f_in.read():  
            decrypted_chunk = decryptor.update(chunk)
            f_out.write(decrypted_chunk)
        f_out.write(decryptor.finalize())

key = os.urandom(32)  
nonce = os.urandom(16) 

encrypt_video('input.mp4', 'encrypted_video.mp4', key, nonce)

decrypt_video('encrypted_video.mp4', 'decrypted_video.mp4', key, nonce)

The encrypted_video.mp4 neither be played by VLC nor streamed using ffmpeg. Any suggestions will be appreciated :(

decrypted_video.mp4 will be a copy of input.mp4, so if the original works then so will the copy. However, the first part of your question and your title talks about streaming decryption so it's not clear what your question is.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk Sorry for any ambiguous, what i'm trying to do is:

encrypt a video using a stream cipher algorithm such as ChaCha20, RC4... (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher)
stream that encrypted video using ffmpeg ( if possible ) and the receiver will use shared key to decrypt it


You should probably put the focus of this question on FFmpeg and its encryption support. I don't know the capabilities of FFmpeg but it does seem to support encryption according to a standard, and using its supported encryption protocols has to be the easiest solution here.

No, you cannot do that the way you are describing it. The reason is that an encrypted stream is fully randomized. So ffmpeg will just see random bytes which are obviously not part of any protocol, so it will never play it. Even if you have a protocol that allows encryption of only the media content itself then you'd just get noise.
You can encrypt, stream using sockets, then decrypt, and then feed it to ffmpeg of course as ffmpeg just sees the plaintext stream in that case. In that case you can e.g. just use TCP or any other generic transport protocol.
I agree with James that using build-in capabilities is easier to use build in functionality. A quick search shows that ffmpeg can support SRTP when configured correctly, which allows for AES encryption.
